# Removing div class from homepage only

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

First I'll start by saying that I'm not PHP savvy in any way.

I want my footer to display on all pages (wordpress site), not a problem right now.  What I want, is for the

`<div class="inner-footer-wrapper">`

to be hidden on the homepage.

Here's what I have in my footer.php

```
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="inner-footer-wrapper">

    <?php if (!is_page_template("template-maintenance-page.php") && $super_options[SN."_footer_widgets"]=="Yes") : ?>
    <div class="container clearfix">  

    <?php 
    $footer_layout = $super_options[SN."_footer_layout"];
    switch($footer_layout)
    {
    case "two-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_half clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_half_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "three-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "four-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "five-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 5"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "six-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 5"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 6"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;

    case "one-third" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols two_third_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-fourth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols three_fourth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-fifth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols four_fifth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-sixth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols five_sixth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;


    }
    ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-menu">
    <div class="container clearfix">

    <p class="footer-text"><?php echo $helper->customFormat($super_options[SN."_footer_text"]); ?></p> 

    <?php  if(!is_page_template("template-maintenance-page.php") && $super_options[SN."_footer_menu"]=="Yes") : 
    if(function_exists("wp_nav_menu"))
    {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'=>'footer_nav',
    'container'=>'ul',
    'depth' => 1
    )
    );
    }
    endif;
    ?>

    </div>      
    </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
    echo stripslashes($super_options[SN."_tracking_code"]);
    ?>
    </script>
    <?php  wp_footer();  ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried to do an if is_home statement but I don't have enough knowledge to know where it goes.  Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking there _must_ be a way to simplify that code. DRY.

Comment: first place is to look in codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything you don't want to show on the homepage with

```
<?php if(!is_home()){?>

             //code here

<?php } ?>
```

or:

```
<div id="footer">
    <?php if(!is_home()){?>
    <div class="inner-footer-wrapper">

    <?php if (!is_page_template("template-maintenance-page.php") && $super_options[SN."_footer_widgets"]=="Yes") : ?>
    <div class="container clearfix">  

    <?php 
    $footer_layout = $super_options[SN."_footer_layout"];
    switch($footer_layout)
    {
    case "two-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_half clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_half_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "three-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "four-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "five-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 5"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "six-col" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 3"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 4"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 5"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 6"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;

    case "one-third" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_third clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols two_third_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-fourth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fourth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols three_fourth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-fifth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_fifth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols four_fifth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;
    case "one-sixth" : 

    echo '<div class="footer-cols one_sixth clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 1"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo '<div class="footer-cols five_sixth_last clearfix">';
    dynamic_sidebar ("Footer Column 2"); 
    echo "</div>"; 

    break;


    }
    ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
    <div id="footer-menu">
    <div class="container clearfix">

    <p class="footer-text"><?php echo $helper->customFormat($super_options[SN."_footer_text"]); ?></p> 

    <?php  if(!is_page_template("template-maintenance-page.php") && $super_options[SN."_footer_menu"]=="Yes") : 
    if(function_exists("wp_nav_menu"))
    {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'=>'footer_nav',
    'container'=>'ul',
    'depth' => 1
    )
    );
    }
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>      
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
    echo stripslashes($super_options[SN."_tracking_code"]);
    ?>
    </script>
    <?php  wp_footer();  ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Turns out there in an error " Fatal error: Call to a member function customFormat() on a non-object in /home/content/44/6120244/html/wp-content/themes/dagda/footer.php on line 164".  Now the footers are showing up under the slider (and are not part of the slider at all)

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant.  The slides that supposed to be part of the slider are showing up under the footer.

Answer (score 1):

on your home page, put this in the body tag-

```
<body <?php $page = "home"; ?>>
```

Now put this in your footer tag-

```
<div class="inner-footer-wrapper" style="display:"<?php if($page == "home"){ echo "none";}?>">
```

Comment: The best way to do your approach would be:

`<body <?php body_class(); ?>> `
Then in the css:
`.home .inner-footer-wrapper {display:none}`